# How to apply PCA for principal component regression?

Tags: regression, pca

I am pretty new to PCA so please bear with me. I have already read some papers and articles online talking about how PCA reduces the dimension, but I'm still not sure how to actually use it.

Say I have a dataset represented as a matrix:

$$[X_1\ X_2\ X_3\ X_4\ X_5\ Y]$$

where $Y$ is my response. Now, do I apply PCA to this whole matrix or only to the independent variables  $[X_1\ X_2\ X_3\ X_4\ X_5 ]$?

I suspect that we are supposed to apply PCA only to $X$'s. Applying PCA to $[X_1\ X_2\ X_3\ X_4\ X_5]$, we will have some eigenvectors and we may pick two of them:

$$\alpha = 0.3X_1 + 0.4 X_5$$ and $$\beta = 0.5X_3 + 0.8 X_4$$

Then we regress $Y$ against $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: First, a remark: in any real (non-artificial) dataset eigenvectors will have non-zero elements for all features, so your $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should probably be linear combinations of all five $X_i$ variables. Apart from that, what you describe in the body of your question is called "principal component regression"; in this framework the answer to the question in your last sentence is **Yes.** But I am confused by your title, which has *nothing* to do with what is described in the question body; could you please edit to make them correspond to each other?

Comment: Thanks. I edited it a bit more. Short answers to your questions are: (1) PCA should be applied only to $X$. (2) Yes.